# Weird ul list issue in my case

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird issue with my ul list

I have something like

```
<section id='slide-container'>
        <h1>Slide</h1>
        <div class='break'></div>
        <div id='left-nav'><a href='#'><img src='images/left-nav.png'/></a></div>
        <ul id='slide-list'>
            <li><img src='images/slide1.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide2.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide3.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide4.png' /></li>
            <li><img src='images/slide5.png' /></li>         
        </ul>
        <div id='right-nav'><a href='#'><img src='images/right-nav.png'/></a></div>
</section>

my css

#slide-container{
    width: 708px;
    height: 1px;
    line-height: 190px;
    border:solid 1px #EEEEEE;
    white-space: nowrap; overflow: auto;
}

#slide-container h1{
    margin:8px 10px 0 10px;
    font-size: .8em;
    display: inline-block;
}

section #slide-list {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 142px;
}

section #slide-list li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 162px;
    height: 142px;
    background-color: grey;
    line-height: 142px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 6px;
}

section #left-nav{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

section #right-nav{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;    
}

.break{
   clear:both;
}
```

For some reason, My slide-list li is pushed down for 20 to 30 px.

My desire results

dash line is slide-container div

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|                                              
|
|  left nav slide slide slide slide right nav
|
| 
 ----------------------------------------------
```

my codes result

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|                                     
|
|  
|    left nav slide slide slide slide right nav
| 
 ----------------------------------------------
```

I don't understand what happen here. I also reset my css to have zero margin and padding for all elements. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A working jsfiddle with real images would be helpful to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

For default all elements has properties in this case `ul`:

```
ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin-before: 1em;
  margin-after: 1em;
  margin-start: 0;
  margin-end: 0;
  padding-start: 40px; 
}
```

You need to reset those properties : Try

```
ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: You may also want to try `display: block` on the ul instead of `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your line-heights. Remove these from `#left-nav`, `#right-nav`, and `#slide-list li`.

Also set the ul's margin to 0 ([@Danko's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20338716) idea).